# @manipulate using in Atom in julia

Tags: julia

I'm learning julia . Is it possible to use @manipulate macro in atom or is there any way to visualize this in ATOM IDE

```
using Plots,Interact


gr()

function sigmoid(z)
    return 1/(1+e^-z)
end

f₁(x,w,b)=sigmoid.(w*x+b)

x=linspace(-10,10,101)



 @manipulate for w=[-10,-5,-2.5,2.5,5,10] ,b=[-10,-5,-2.5,0,2.5,5,10]
        y=f₁(x,w,b)
        plot(x,y,label="sigmoid $w and $b",xlabel="x",ylabel="y",ylims=(0,1))
end
```

Comment: Check out [InteractNext.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/InteractNext.jl), *it also works in the Atom/Juno IDE*

Comment: @Ismael Venegas Castelló Thank you.. But InteractNext is throwing error for sin , cos function. It is only working for sigmoid